# Access body from Nested Master Page in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, master-pages

I've got the current setup:

MyMasterPage.Master

**MyMasterPage2.Master** which has MyMasterPage.Master as MasterPage and extends it by several ContentPlaceHolders.

Several aspx-forms, some of them with MyMasterPage as Master and some of them with **MyMasterPage2** as Master.

Now I'd like to access the **body**-Tag (which is defined in MyMasterPage) in **MyMasterPage2** in order to change the CSS-Class.

Is there any way to do so?

Thanks,

Dennis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution which won't break if you later change your masterpage structures is to just add the following line of [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').addClass('mycssclass');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I was so obsessed with finding a solution using the CodeBehind-Files that I didn't even think about such an easy approach.

Comment: Hehe, I know that feeling :-)